# what's you deeply understanding with shared files &unshared files in linux

Tags: linux, filesystems

In linux root directory! there are some static shared directories ex:/usr & /opt;these directories can mount read-only device;There are some others like /etc & /boot they are static unshared directory;I konw these concepts but I really not get the difference between shared and unshared;

Comment: One important difference is that /etc and /boot are system directories, while /usr and /opt are associated with user software.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not these directories are "shared" is dependent upon permissions.
Root has access to nearly everything.
Permissions are:

```
U - User (the current owner)
G - Group (permissions for any group the user is a member of or the owning group)
O - Other (everyone permissions)

R - Read access
W - Write access
X - Execute access (run file as executable)
```

You shouldn't mount to random directories unless you know what you're doing. If you want to mount a filesystem, place a folder under /media or /mnt and attach there.

Also as fixer1234 said, certain folders are accessible to all users because they contain applications.